# Script doesn't work if elements are not located

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I tried to automate a website but when it goes to a page that has no elements, it's doesn't run anymore. For example this page: https://www.marks4sure.com/9A0-127-exam.html
What I want to do is if it doesn't exist any details, it should return back and then proceed with the next one.

Thanks for the help.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
# option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
#     "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
# })
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Awais\\Desktop\\web crawling\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(100)

url = "https://www.marks4sure.com/allexams.html"

driver.get(url)

links = []
exam_code = []
exam_name = []
total_q = []

for x in range(70):
    for i in range(1, 57):
        more_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/h5/a')
        links.append(more_details.get_attribute('href'))
        more_details.click()

        try:
            code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]')
            exam_code.append(code.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')
        try:
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a')
            exam_name.append(name.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')
        try:
            question = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/strong')
            total_q.append(question.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')

        driver.back()

    next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yw0"]/li[13]')
    next_page.click()

all_info = list(zip(links, exam_name, exam_name, total_q))
print(all_info)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_info, columns = ["Links", "Exam Code", "Exam Name", "Total Question"])
df.to_csv("data.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')

driver.close()
```

Comment: Anyone here to help?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you are getting, and the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not check for more details elements

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
# option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
#     "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
# })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Awais\\Desktop\\web crawling\\chromedriver.exe')


driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

url = "https://www.marks4sure.com/allexams.html"

driver.get(url)

links = []
exam_code = []
exam_name = []
total_q = []

for x in range(70):
    for i in range(1, 57):
        try:
            more_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/h5/a')
            links.append(more_details.get_attribute('href'))
            more_details.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue

        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div').get_attribute('class') == 'alert alert-danger':
                drier.back()
                continue
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]')
            exam_code.append(code.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')
        try:
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a')
            exam_name.append(name.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')
        try:
            question = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/strong')
            total_q.append(question.text)
        except:
            print('N/A')

        driver.back()
    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yw0"]/li[13]')
        next_page.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()

all_info = list(zip(links, exam_name, exam_name, total_q))
print(all_info)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_info, columns=["Links", "Exam Code", "Exam Name", "Total Question"])

driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi, @4rigener I tried your code but it's not working. Can you recheck, please?

Comment: @Awais If you add error what it is, then it will help

Comment: Alright, if you run the script it will work just fine but when there is no "code", "name" or "question" of the page which is being scraped by the script, the script stopped there and doesn't come back to the listing page to scrape the next one. If you run the script you will know what I mean :)

Comment: @Awais I edit the code, how about this one? I test the code before, but I can't because site very slow

Comment: still having the same issue. I made a video for you. this will explain you better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLCyAXohwd4

I want the script to skip if it sees no content.

Comment: @Awais attatch error at your post, not just situation, full error comment showing. And in site what you want scrap, there's support alert appeared after seconds. If there's change at html code, then selenium need to find elements again. This not automatic, you need to do yourself. Because DOM maybe?

Comment: @Awais I find the cause, `driver.implicitly_wait(100)` is bad code. If you need element that need to wait, then just attach wait to that element. Not for all. I edit code. It works at my computer.

Comment: @Awais If webpage stuck for some reason, just refresh spend 1 seconds, but `driver.implicitly_wait(100)` always spend 100 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the `NoSuchElementException` when finding `more_details`, go back and continue to the next iteration of the loop:

```
for x in range(70):
    for i in range(1, 57):
        more_details = None

        try:
            more_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/h5/a')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.back()
            continue

        links.append(more_details.get_attribute('href'))
        # rest of the code...
```

Comment: Hi, Greg, I tried your code but it's not working. Can you recheck, please? It's still the same issue.